# Modern templating solution for Yii 1.1

Tags: templates, yii, yii1.x, templating-engine

I know that Yii 1.1 is a bit outdated framework, but I would still like to ask if there is a modern templating solution available to be plugged into an existing Yii 1.1 project?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but you can try [smarty](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/smarty-view-renderer) extensions for yii1